# Go HTTP package with custom network layer

Tags: http, go, networking

I'm trying to write an HTTP package in Go that uses a custom network layer, not IP. My goal is to have a package that offers the same interface as the net/http package in the standard library such that existing applications can just swap the package for mine and they would still work.

My question is how I should go about this. It seems to me that I have to fork the whole net/http package and replace calls to the network with my network layer. However, this doesn't seem very elegant as it's basically just duplicating code apart from some changes. Is there another way to re-use the existing http package?

Comment: What parts do you need to replace? Everything is done through the `net.Conn` Interface.

Comment: My network package implements the `net.Conn` interface.
What I'm not sure about is how to make the `net/http` package use this new iplementation of the interface without replacing it everywhere in the code.

Comment: If you implement `net.Conn`, then you just use your implementation. Can you show a specific problem you’re having doing that?

Comment: @JimB I'm guessing the OP wants an example for how to hook into the APIs . For an HTTP server I guess the answer is to implement net.Listener whose Accept() method returns the custom net.Conn. For an HTTP client doing `http.Get(...)` I can't quite figure out where the hook would be.

Comment: @nos, the “hooks” are the same as for the `net` package, a `net.Listener` for the server, and the `Transport` Has `Dial*` functions for getting connections. It’s all documented there, but I can write up an answer if I have time later.